# RECV Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, sockets, dynamic, recv

In C I am looking to read the html of a page, but I want the buffer that is holding the data to be dynamic. I know that I will have to do this with a loop and the use of `realloc` but I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that. Assuming I have my socket (`sock`) already open consider the following:

```
char *buffer = ???, *tmp;  //just my guess I'm fairly certain buffer cannot be NULL considering my recv loop...
int q = 0, c;
int i = 1;       //buffer size

    while(q < i)
{
    c == recv(sock, buffer + q, i - q, 0);
    if(c == SOCKET_ERROR) break;
    i += c;
    tmp = realloc(buffer, i * sizeof(char));
    //if(!tmp) /*not important right now I can add error handling later*/;
    buffer = tmp;      
    q += c;
}
```

This would be my best guess on how to achieve my goal, but I highly doubt this will work, and I just need some insight or correction.

Comment: you can use the `MSG_PEEK` flag parameter to see how big the message actually is and just allocate it in one go, no need for `realloc`.

Comment: Not to be needy but can you give me some sample code on how you would do that? And thank you for your answer. This isn't school related, more personal interest related.

Comment: @Necrolis: Can you give me an example to update my code? I don't know as do it. I'm missing something.`char buffer[128]; size = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_PEEK);` Will `sizeof(buffer)` always less than or equal to `size`. Never greater than, right?

Comment: `size` can be greater when using `MSG_PEEK`, however the size can change between peeking and reading, so its more a minimum size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some bad errors in the code:

```
c == recv(...
```

`==` is a comparison, not assignment, you will ever get either `0` or `1`. Then:

```
tmp = realloc(buffer, i * sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, and you have to check the return value against `NULL`. Also, name your variables something meaningful - will save you a lot of grief later.

Now, you are trying to do something like "post-allocation" - read into a buffer and then extend it to the size you just got - kind of backwards.

Simple solution (one of many):

- allocate the buffer upfront,
- read into it in a loop keeping track of the accumulated size (and thus the offset),
- if you run out of buffer space - re-allocate it to **twice the size** of the previous one, and continue.

This *works most of the time<sup>TM</sup>*. You might want to add some sanity checks not to gobble all your memory if the other side keeps feeding you data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I just kind of marked that up right here just because it was a problem I faced yesterday, thanks so much for your help!